# How to format Currency format in dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

i have a product and its price is 100,000,000, but the sever returns me 100000000,
so I used NumberFormat to convert it to the format I wanted,
and here is the code i do but it is giving error, can someone point out what i'm doing wrong

```
final oCcy =  NumberFormat("#,###", "en_US");
 => oCcy.format(100000000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sharing my code it will surely work :

```
final oCcy = NumberFormat.currency(
  locale: 'eu',
  customPattern: '#,### \u00a4',
  symbol: 'FCFA',
  decimalDigits: 2);

print(oCcy.format(12345)) // 12.345,00 FCFA
```